# How can I save or get data about places near me without breaking policies

Tags: api, google-maps, mapbox, openstreetmap, here-api

This is more of a general programming question.

I'm trying to create an app, think of it as a Yelp clone. I have most of it working but I'm missing one important feature. The data of the places around me. For now I'm only focused on food, so I'd like it if I search something like "Pizza", it'd show me all the pizza joints near me.

I was originally planning to use Google Places API. However if you havent heard, they're changing their pricing and lowering the free tier and upping the cost by a huge margin.

There's also the problem of saving the data. One workaround I saw a user suggest was to just keep using Google's API, but every time you make the query, store the data in your own DB as well (I only need address and name and latitude and longitude) so eventually, you'd have what you need in a sense. However I also want to have something like a simple rating system for each place like Yelp, but Google (and all other places like MapBox, Here Maps, etc) states something along the lines of "info from their API should not be stored or cached for more than 24hrs" but it's very broad and not specific.

So what I was planning to do was, call the Google API, grab the 3 info I need (Address, Name, Lat/Lng), add more fields to store the rating, likes, whatever else the user will add. Then store it in my database, but that doesn't seem like a solution now.

So does anyone have any ideas or advice? Or know of a service where I can get the details of all the food places? And if possible, can anyone confirm that storing the Name, Address, Lat&Lng is a violation of their policy since in my eyes, it's public data, but something like the rating that Google provides, or the pictures that Google provides, now that's Google property.

Comment: what was your solution for this? I need to do something very similar.

Answer (score 0):

For obtaining places you can use OpenStreetMap, e.g. using Overpass API. Since larger traffic can be expected you should run your own database(s) instead of using the public APIs.

However OSM doesn't contain ratings. So you have to combine this data with some other publicly available rating system.